# XMPP multi device sync

Tags: xmpp

I am trying to develop a messaging application using XMPP. I am trying to implement chat sync on multiple devices per user. But I am able to get the messages only on the logged devices or the  first offline device which logs in.  Different devices use different resource so that full jabber id is different.
Scenario is,

1. A logs in on one device.
2. A sends some messages to B
3. B logs in on his first device and it receives a message from A.
4. B logs in on his other device, but does not get the message from A. (This is device will not be in proper sync)

I already have message carbons and archiving enabled.
Is there a way I can get these messages on the other device of B?

Thanks,
Puneet

Answer (score 0):

Retrive archived messages from server that will solve your problem.
You can use custom IQ to get archived messages from server. And [follow this format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163681/retrieve-history-chat-openfire-xmpp-framework/39236173#39236173) for custom IQ.

Answer (score 0):

In order to participate in the instant messaging and presence activities, a client (i.e device) should establish a session on the server.

As given in [XMPP Documentation](https://xmpp.org/rfcs/rfc3921.html)

> If there is already an active resource of the same name, the server
> MUST either (1) terminate the active resource and allow the
> newly-requested session, or (2) disallow the newly-requested session
> and maintain the active resource. Which of these the server does is up
> to the implementation, although it is RECOMMENDED to implement case #1. In case #1, the server SHOULD send a  stream error to the active resource, terminate the XML stream and underlying TCP
> connection for the active resource, and return a IQ stanza of type
> "result" (indicating success) to the newly-requested session. In case #2, the server SHOULD send a  stanza error to the newly-requested session but maintain the XML stream for that
> connection so that the newly-requested session has an opportunity to
> negotiate a non-conflicting resource identifier before sending another
> request for session establishment.

(https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6120#section-7.7.2.2)

However, if you still want to use multiple sessions you can use Message Archive Management -  [XEP-0313](https://xmpp.org/extensions/xep-0313.html)