# Openfire ConversationID has changed after logout

Tags: xmpp, openfire, xmppframework

I'm developing a chat app that use XMPPFramework and Openfire Server. When I (usn2) send message to usn1, a message has been created in ofMessageArchieve with conversationID. But after logout and login again, when chat, the new conversation has created (see image below), but I want to add this message to exist conversation. How can I do this?

Code to send message:

```
let msg = XMPPMessage(type: "chat", to: XMPPJID.jidWithString(getJIDFromName(stateID)))
msg.addBody(message)
msg.addAttributeWithName("id", stringValue: stream.generateUUID())
stream.sendElement(msg)
```

[image]

Although I changed Openfire as @Shoaib Ahmad Gondal suggested. It still happens
[image]

Comment: Can you apply the changes in Openfire suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163681/retrieve-history-chat-openfire-xmpp-framework#comment65742736_39163681 and then check if you still experience this?

Comment: @ShoaibAhmadGondal I changed, but it may not affect

Answer (score 0):

MessageId and ConversationId is not same. MessageId generates for each message you send but ConversationId generates based on users & session(maybe). To keep them same you have to modify message archive plugin or develop new one.

Comment: Yes, I know MessageId and ConversationId are different. 1 conversation have many messages. May you misunderstood my problem. Ex: I'm user1, chat with user2, 1 conversation will be created with conversationID=1 for example. But after 1 day, when user1 and user2 chat again, a new conversation (conversationID=2) has been created. I want they continue  to chat in conversation1. And I  want to know how to do this?

Comment: I got your problem so I have mentioned that maybe conversationId are generated based on session (every time you login that creates a new sessoin), If so you have to customize it.

Comment: I've solved this :D. You can check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39163681/retrieve-history-chat-openfire-xmpp-framework/39236173#39236173

Comment: well thats also answered by me but thats related to "How to get chat history"